# Not able see any option to disable Automatically Prompt before download in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Recently, whenever I'm printing a file from IE, I'm getting a prompt to save or open the file before printing. I tried to disable this prompt under security tab-Custom level-Downloads in Internet option but I'm not able to find the option to disable the automatic prompt. This started happening from last week.
I'm using Internet Explorer 11.
Please let me know if anyone has any idea why the option is not visible or anyway to disable this prompt and directly send file to printer.

Comment: At present, there is no way to disable that prompt. Does the suggestion I provided you in the answer to help you to get the answer for your question? If yes, you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure Which kind of file you are trying to print. But it looks like that file format is not supported by the IE browser.

Generally, when you try to open the file that is not supported by the IE browser it will show you that prompt and give you the option to save or open that file.

If we talk about that prompt then at present there is no way to disable that prompt.

In the older versions of the IE browser has the option to disable this prompt. In those older versions, there was a way to disable this prompt using the registry key. For security purposes, these options were removed in the IE 10 and IE 11 version.

I suggest you use the dedicated application for that file type and try to print the file from that application.

For example, if you want to print the word document then try to use MS Word application to print it.